# how to fix "missing argument label in call" in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

i'm a totally beginner of swift and ios programming
and i met a question by following a coding lesson video which was written by swift 1 and xcode 6 beta.
i know the version of swift had changed ,and the syntax had been changed a lot two.
and i have fix some problems but there is still one that i can't deal with.
That's "missing argument label in call"

the following is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManger:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var temperature: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManger.delegate = self

    locationManger.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if(ios10()) {
        locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManger.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func ios10() ->Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.systemVersion == "10.2"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let location:CLLocation = locations[locations.count-1] as CLLocation

    if(location.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
        print(location.coordinate.latitude)
        print(location.coordinate.longitude)
        self.updateWeatherInfo(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        locationManger.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func updateWeatherInfo(latitude:CLLocationDegrees,longitude:CLLocationDegrees){
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=c5a8f49ee6e86f1aaa2be178f25f37f2"
    let params = ["lat":latitude,"lon":longitude,"cnt":0]

    manager.get(url,
                parameters: params,
                success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: Any!) in
                    print("JSON:" + (responseObject as AnyObject).description!)

                    updateUISuccess(responseObject as! NSDictionary!)  
//that's where my error1 :missing argument label 'jsonResult' in call
                }
    )
}

func updateUISuccess(jsonResult:NSDictionary){

    if let tempResult = (jsonResult["main"] as? [String:Double])?["type"] {
        //if let tempResult = (jsonResult["main"] as? [String:Double])?["type"]  current
        //if let tempResult = jsonResult["main"]?["temp"]? as? Double   pre

        var temperature:Double
        if ((jsonResult["sys"] as? [String:String])?["country"] == "US"){
            //CONVERT TO FAHRENHEIT IF USER IN US
            temperature = round(((temperature - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32)
        }
        else{
            //CONVERT TO CELSIUS
            temperature = round(temperature - 273.15)
        }

        self.temperature.text = "\(temperature)°"
        print(temperature)

        var name = jsonResult["name"] as! String
        self.location.text = "\(name)"


        var conditionArray = (jsonResult["weather"] as! NSArray)[0] as! NSDictionary  
        var condition = conditionArray["id"] as! Int    

        var sunrise = (jsonResult["sys"] as? [String:Double])?["sunrise"]
        var sunset = (jsonResult["sys"] as? [String:Double])?["sunset"]

        var nightTime = false
        var now = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        if (now < sunrise! || now > sunset!) {
            nightTime = true
        }
        //self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"sunny")
        updateWeatherIcon(condition,nightTime: nightTime)
//that's where my error2 :missing argument label 'condition:' in call
    }
    else {
        print("error!")
    }


}

func updateWeatherIcon(condition: Int,nightTime: Bool){
    //thunderstorm
    if(condition < 300) {
        if nightTime {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"tstorm1_night")
        }
        else {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"tstorm1")
        }
    }
        //drizzle
    else if (condition < 500) {

    }
        //rain
    else if (condition < 600) {

    }
        //snow
    else if (condition < 700) {

    }
        //fog
    else if (condition < 771) {
        if nightTime {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named: "fog_night")
        }
        else {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named: "fog")
        }
    }
        //tornado
    else if (condition < 800) {
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"tstorm3")
    }
        //clear
    else if (condition == 800) {
        if nightTime {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"sunny_night")
        }
        else {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"sunny")
        }
    }
        //few clouds
    else if (condition < 804) {
        if nightTime {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"cloudy2_night")
        }
        else {
            self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"cloudy2")
        }
    }
        //overcast
    else if (condition == 804) {
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"overcast")
    }
        //extreme
    else if ((condition >= 900 && condition < 903) || (condition >= 904 && condition < 1000)){
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"tstorm3")
    }
        //cold
    else if (condition == 903) {
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"snow5")
    }
        //hot
    else if (condition == 904) {
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"sunny")
    }
        //dont know
    else {
        self.icon.image = UIImage(named:"dono")
    }
}



func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error){
    print(error)
}

}
```

i want to know how to fix it 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The error is because your function requires that you name the argument you are passing in. Try changing:

```
updateUISuccess(responseObject as! NSDictionary!)
```

To:

```
updateUISuccess(jsonResult: responseObject as! NSDictionary!)
```

Alternatively, you can define the function like this to not require the parameter to be named:

```
func updateUISuccess(_ jsonResult:NSDictionary){
```

Note the underscore.

Your second error has a similar cause, so change:

```
updateWeatherIcon(condition,nightTime: nightTime)
```

to:

```
updateWeatherIcon(condition: condition, nightTime: nightTime)
```

Comment: i have tried it ,but new error and warning would show up .

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate, my suggestions are these: (1) First, make sure you understand what was the issue in this post. Swift 3 *requires* named parameters for *all* parameters not prefixed with an underscore. Older versions of Swift had an *implied* underscore for the first parameter. (2) If you are now getting different errors, post *both* the relevant code *and* the error in a new question.

Comment: .let me show you.    error: 'Variable 'temperature' used before being initialized' .                           warning:'Variable name,conditonArray,condition,sunrise,sunset and now was never mutated;condiser changing to 'let' constant'                                           why does this appear?

Comment: This is a different error. Your **var temperature:Double**, while declaring things, didn't set a value. A few lines down, inside your if statement you are essentially saying **temperature = [some calculations on temperature]**. What is temperature? Sure, you know it's a double, but what *value* is it? If I were to guess, it's probably the **tempResult** you set up from the jsonResult a few lines above.